# Combine Dataframes with Minute and Date Indexes

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Say I have the following dataframes; one with data on 1 minute intervals, and the another with daily data intervals.

```
>>> df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                 'B':[4,5,6],
                 'C':[7,8,9]}, 
                 index=pd.to_datetime(['2017-01-01 00:01:00', '2017-01-01 00:02:00', '2017-01-02 00:01:00']))

>>> df_1
                     A  B  C
2017-01-01 00:01:00  1  4  7
2017-01-01 00:02:00  2  5  8
2017-01-02 00:01:00  3  6  9

>>> df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'D':['ON','OFF']}, 
                 index=pd.to_datetime(['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02']))
>>> df_2
              D
2017-01-01   ON
2017-01-02  OFF
```

And I want to merge them so that the data from df_2 gets pulled into df_1 by the date only, as below.

```
>>> df_merge = pd.merge(df_1, df_2)
>>> df_merge

                     A  B  C    D
2017-01-01 00:01:00  1  4  7   ON
2017-01-01 00:02:00  2  5  8   ON
2017-01-02 00:01:00  3  6  9  OFF
```

Is there any way to merge based on date only that will pull the daily data into the minutely data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `reindex`

```
df_1['D']=df_2.reindex(df_1.index,method='nearest')
df_1
Out[184]: 
                     A  B  C    D
2017-01-01 00:01:00  1  4  7   ON
2017-01-01 00:02:00  2  5  8   ON
2017-01-02 00:01:00  3  6  9  OFF
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
If your dataframes are sorted by index, then `pd.merge_asof` should also work:

```
pd.merge_asof(df_1, df_2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

                     A  B  C    D
2017-01-01 00:01:00  1  4  7   ON
2017-01-01 00:02:00  2  5  8   ON
2017-01-02 00:01:00  3  6  9  OFF
```

---

**Option 2**
If not, then you can construct a general solution using `merge` on a temporary column constructed from the floored date of `df_1`'s index:

```
df_1.assign(temp=df_1.index.floor('D')).merge(
     df_2, left_on='temp', right_index=True
).drop('temp', 1)

                     A  B  C    D
2017-01-01 00:01:00  1  4  7   ON
2017-01-01 00:02:00  2  5  8   ON
2017-01-02 00:01:00  3  6  9  OFF
```

---

**Option 3**
Using `concat`:

```
idx = df_1.index
pd.concat([df_1.set_index(df_1.index.floor('D')), df_2], 1).set_index(idx)

                     A  B  C    D
2017-01-01 00:01:00  1  4  7   ON
2017-01-01 00:02:00  2  5  8   ON
2017-01-02 00:01:00  3  6  9  OFF
```